# Gnome Tweaks Tool doesn't recognise a theme

Tags: gnome, themes

I was trying to install a theme ([this one](https://www.gnome-look.org/p/1403328/)).
I extracted the theme folder and (by tiping in the terminal sudo nautilus) i moved it on the folder usr>share>themes.
Then, everytime that i opne the tweaks app, it doesn't recognise the theme.
What I've done wrong?

Ubuntu version: 20.10 -
Gnome version: 3.38.3

Answer (score 3):

You need to copy the extracted file to **`.local/share/themes`**. If there isn`t any folder named themes, you can create one too.

Open your **Home** directory. Press `CTRL + h` to show the hidden files. You will find `.local` directory there. Go to the path specified above and paste the extracted files. Then you may be able to see the theme in the Gnome Tweaks. If not, restart Ubuntu.